# Discord.py Json file instead of adding new values, json replace all the values with one

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, bots, discord.py

so, i made  command where i store user input into a json file, there's the code :

```
       for user in client.users:
            with open('suggestions.json', 'r') as f:
                h = json.load(f)

             h[str(f'{user.id} | {user.name} ')] = message.content

            with open('suggestions.json', 'w') as f:
                json.dump(h, f, indent=4)
```

The problem is that when two  or more different users use the command all their input changes in the last one input like :

```
{
    "ID| USER NAME ": "ol",
    "ID | USER NAME ": "ol",
    "ID | USER NAME ": "ol"
}
```

and for some reason is storing also the bot name and id with the user input and all members or bots that are typing in that second  with the same value as the one who casted the command, i tried lots of things, i really don't have any idea, just maybe using a db but atm i don't have knowledge about this.

for a better view, my command looks like this at this moment :

```
@client.command()
async def suggestion(ctx):
    await ctx.send("You want to submit a suggestion?")
    message = await client.wait_for ('message' ,timeout=25, check = lambda m: m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel)

    if message.content == "yes"  :
        await ctx.send("Good choice, now let's hear your suggestion : ")

        message = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=25, check=lambda m: m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel)
        await ctx.send("Alirght, i will send this suggestion to the developer, thanks ! ")
        for user in client.users:
            with open('suggestions.json', 'r') as f:
                h = json.load(f)

            h[str(f'{user.id} | {user.name} ')] = message.content

            with open('suggestions.json', 'w') as f:
                json.dump(h, f, indent=4)

    elif message.content == "no":
        await ctx.send("Too bad, please use this command just if you have any ideas.")
```

Answer (score 1):

so, you are making a simple suggest command, this is the way used to store data in json perfectly:)

```
def saveJson(data, file):
    json.dump(data, open(file, "w"), indent = 4)

_suggestions = open('./suggestions.json', 'r')
suggestions = json.load(f)
_suggestions.close()

@client.command()
async def suggest(ctx, *, message):
    user = ctx.author.id
    username = str(ctx.author)
    for current_user in suggestions['users']:
        if current_user['id'] == user:
            current_user['suggestions'].append(message)
            if username != current_user['name']:
                current_user['name'] = username
            break
    else:
        suggestions['users'].append({
            'id':user,
            'name':username,
            'suggestions': [message]
        })
    saveJson(suggestions, "./suggestions.json")
```

your json file should look like this,

```
{
    'users': [
        {
            'id': 123456789,
            'name': 'billy#1234',
            'suggestions: [
                'be good',
                'drink milk',
                'eat cookies'
            ]
        },
        {
            'id': 1234512345,
            'name': 'willy#1234',
            'suggestions: [
                'don't be good',
                'don't drink milk',
                'don't eat cookies',
                'drink orange juice'
            ]
        }
}
```

and, by making a suggestions comman, you can retrieve all suggestions by a user, let me know, if you'd like to know how to do that :)

Comment: your version looks nice, i just edited my question to see the full code, so you can make a general idea of how the code should be, i hope this helps, so now the questios is, how i can implement your solution to my code @BillyDev

Comment: and also i have bunch of errors because of  ` _suggestions = open('suggestions.json', 'r') as f:
suggestions = json.load(f) `
errors like " Statement expected, found Py:AS_KEYWORD, End of statement expected , Expression expected, Name 'f' can be undefined, Redeclared '_suggestions' defined above without usage" this, in just two lines. looked pretty well, but when i analyzed the code..

Comment: check it again, it should be fixed :)